# Fastest way to write a number in the format of $8\times A\times B$

Tags: calculus

example

split $5216$ into two numbers. Then write both of these numbers in the format of $8\times A\times B$. One parameter of the second number should not be bigger than $10$, while one parameter in the first number should not smaller than $30$

$$44\times13\times8=4576$$

$$5\times16\times8=640$$

Is there a trick to figure out fast how to choose the correct split numbers, since the given numbers have to be divisible by 8$?$

Comment: Maybe you should first consider the number divided by $8$?

Answer (score 0):

saying for 5216, note that it is $5200 + 16$, that is $(650+2)*8$ now you can factorize $652$ as $163*4$ or $326*2$ . Both of these fit in both the conditions.

That is how I try to do fast factorization. Find a nearer number, about which you have some knowledge and then breakup the number as sum of two numbers, and then factorize these easier numbers.